# Porque inverter o índice do array em um for, para popular o array, torna o processo mais rápido?

Tags: java, array, desempenho

Eu estava fazendo uns testes em Java e percebi uma comportamento muito estranho. Fiz um array com duas dimensões e populei o array de duas formas diferentes, preenchendo com números aleatórios até 2^31-1 e apenas mudando o seu índice. Obtive um ganho de desempenho considerável fazendo isto, mas não compreendo o motivo.

Eis o código:

```
public class Array {

    static int tamanhoX = 12000;
    static int tamanhoY = 12000;
    static int array[][] = new int[tamanhoX][tamanhoY];
    static long tempoInicio = 0, tempoFim = 0;
    static double mediaTempo = 0.0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Armazena o tempo das operações
        long tempos[] = new long[10];

        //Calcula o tempo da operação diversas vezes:
        for (int i = 0; i < tempos.length; i++) {
            //Armazena o valor retornado dentro do array: tempos[] na posição: i
            tempos[i] = calculaTempo();
        }

        //Soma todos os valores armazenados no array: tempos[]
        for (int i = 0; i < tempos.length; i++) {
            mediaTempo += tempos[i];
        }

        System.out.println("Tempo total: " + (mediaTempo / 1000) + "s");
        mediaTempo = mediaTempo / tempos.length;//Calcula média
        System.out.println("Média de tempo é de: " + mediaTempo + "ms");
    }

    static long calculaTempo() {
        //Armazena o momento de início da operação em milisegundos
        tempoInicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < tamanhoX; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tamanhoY; j++) {
                //Preenche com um valor aleatório:
                //Mais lento
                //array[j][i] = (int) (Math.random() * Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                //Mais rápido
                array[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            }
        }
        //Armazena o tempo final da operação
        tempoFim = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Tempo: " + (tempoFim - tempoInicio) + "ms");
        return (tempoFim - tempoInicio);
    }
}
```

Percebam que eu só mudei uma única linha, a de atribuição do array. Nos meus testes tive uma média de 90 segundos para:

```
array[j][i] = (int) (Math.random() * Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

e 48 segundos para:

```
array[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Gostaria muito de entender o motivo disto. Porque essa diferença de tempo em apenas inverter o índice do array?

**Atenção!** Não executem este código em computadores com pouca memória. Há o risco de travar seu sistema operacional.

Comment: A minha pergunta ficou um pouco estranha, fiquem a vontade para editar.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nos processadores modernos o gargalo não está na CPU, mas sim na [cache](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache). Isso significa que o programa mais rápido não é [necessariamente] aquele que executa menos instruções, mas sim aquele que acessa a memória de forma mais eficiente (i.e. causa menos *cache misses*).

Em Java, um array multidimensional é representado como um "array de arrays". Isso significa que o primeiro array é um array de referências, e os demais são arrays de inteiros. Ambos tentam ocupar posições contíguas de memória:

```
int[][] array = new int[4][4];
// É equivalente a:
int[] a = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
int[] b = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
int[] c = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
int[] d = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
int[][] array = { a, b, c, d };
```

Vamos supor, para simplificar, que sua cache L1 tem tamanho `4`, e que há apenas duas "páginas" disponíveis. No princípio, `array` está na cache. Quando seu loop faz:

```
array[0][0] = ...;
```

Ele tenta carregar `array` (ótimo, já está na cache!) e depois `a` (não está na cache, busque no nível seguinte e/ou na memória RAM). Em seguida, ele atribui normalmente.

Se depois disso ele fizer:

```
array[0][1] = ...;
```

Ele vai encontrar `array` na cache e `a` também na cache! A operação é bastante rápida. O mesmo vale para `array[0][2]` e `array[0][3]`. Só quando ele tentar atribuir `array[1][0]` é que ele não vai achar `b` na cache - e vai ter que buscar.

Mas se em vez disso ele fizer:

```
array[1][0] = ...;
```

Então `b` não vai estar na cache, e ele vai ter que buscar imediatamente. Depois vem o `array[2][0]`, e veja: `c` também não está na cache, lá vai ele buscar de novo. No momento em que ele voltar ao `array[1][1]` ele vai ter carregado e descarregado toda a região de memória do seu programa na cache, e agora vai ter que fazer tudo de novo...

Na prática, a diferença só não é mais gritante porque a cache não é assim tão pequena, e existem vários níveis (L1, L2...) - de modo que mesmo que sua estrutura de dados não esteja na L1 talvez ela esteja na L2 (i.e. não tem que buscar lá do início). Mas quanto maior forem os dados, maior se torna essa diferença - em especial se a memória física acabar e ele começar a paginar (i.e. usar memória virtual/swap).

Comment: Excelente explicação! Muito obrigado...

Eu pesquisei mais um pouco sobre o assunto, fiquei fascinado com essa técnica. É incrível como o conhecimento a nível de hardware faz com que você desenvolva bons softwares.

Answer (score 3):

Conforme já dito, o processador possui uma pequena quantidade de memória cache, o [**TLB**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_Lookaside_Buffer), que guarda posições de memória acessadas recentemente, e esta memória contida no processador, tem velocidade de leitura/escrita mais rápida que a `RAM` já que a `RAM` depende de barramentos e etc. e o `TLB` fica direto no processador junto com a [**MMU**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidade_de_gerenciamento_de_mem%C3%B3ria).

Se percorremos o laço *for* coluna por coluna (verticalmente) sendo que o cache `TLB` armazena linearmente (horizontalmente) o cache é "desperdiçado" porque ele tem um tamanho relativamente pequeno e os dados dele são sobrescritos sempre com endereços de memória mais recentes, mas se percorremos o laço linearmente, o cache `TLB` será reutilizado reaproveitando os últimos endereços de memória consultados. Esse aproveitamento é que gera o ganho de desempenho, já que o processador não precisa consultar na memória `RAM` a tabela de endereços, economizando vários ciclos de máquina.

Acho que esse cache existe em todos os processadores atuais, ele gera um ganho de desempenho muito grande, é um item indispensável hoje em dia.

Tem um artigo bastante interessante de um assunto relacionado [**aqui**](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1814327), vale a pena dar uma lida.

#### **Fontes**

1. http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_Lookaside_Buffer
2. [http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidade_de_gerenciamento_de_memória](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidade_de_gerenciamento_de_mem%C3%B3ria)
3. http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1814327
4. http://www.hardware.com.br/termos/tlb